# Improve performance of js animation

Tags: javascript, performance, animation

I've made a sine wave animation with javascript where the area below the sine wave is filled with a light blue color. But when I run the code my computer starts heating up and lags. This could also be beacause my computer is pretty worn out by now, but I really would like to know how to optimize this code or maybe recreate the effect with something else that isn't so performance intensive if possible.

The Sine wave animation:
https://jsfiddle.net/x2audoqk/13/

The code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const c = canvas.getContext("2d")

canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    canvas.width = innerWidth
    canvas.height = innerHeight
    wave.y = canvas.height / 1.5
    wave.length = -4.5 / canvas.width
    amplitude = canvas.width / 35
})

const wave = {
    y: canvas.height / 1.5,
    length: -4.5 / canvas.width,
    amplitude: canvas.width / 25,
    frequency: 0.0045
}

let increment = wave.frequency

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)

    // Deletes previous waves
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    c.beginPath()

    // Get all the points on the line so you can modify it with Sin
    for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.width; i++) {
        c.moveTo(i, wave.y + Math.sin(i * wave.length + increment) * wave.amplitude * Math.sin(increment))
        c.lineTo(i, canvas.height)
    }

    // Fill the path
    c.strokeStyle = 'rgba(1, 88, 206, .25)'
    c.stroke()
    increment += wave.frequency
    c.closePath()
}
animate()
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Sine waves are periodic by definition. The common technique to optimize periodic functions is to precalculate each of its values for a period and store them in an array. Then instead of calculating its value in real time you just lookup the value in the array which is O(1) and use modulo arithmetic to wrap back to the beginning when the time variable (in this case) goes beyond the period.

Comment: Have you tried calling requestAnimationFrame after drawing the wave?

Comment: @Ood how does that helps?

Comment: @ThanhTrung I don't know if it will help — perhaps it won't. That's why I suggested to try it out. The reasoning being that the next frame will be requested AFTER the repaint. But as I said this is only speculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heavy load is due to `requestAnimationFrame` which run over and over again. An approach is to limit the frame rate of the animation. Knowing that the human's eyes need at least 24 fps for a fluid image, you can pick a fps between 24-60 fps of your choice (limited by monitor refresh rate up to 60Hz depends on configuration but this is mostly the default).

Here is [a guide](https://codetheory.in/controlling-the-frame-rate-with-requestanimationframe/) how to control the fps

```
var fps = 30;
var now;
var then = Date.now();
var interval = 1000/fps;
var delta;

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    now = Date.now();
    delta = now - then;

    if (delta > interval) {             
        then = now - (delta % interval);

        //your code drawing here
    }
}  
animate();
```

[The the difference between 30 fps and 60 fps](https://www.testufo.com)

Another technique to achieve the same effect with less workload is to use CSS animation (horizontal), with your background wave pre-draw as an image.